# Change component values dynamically in Yii 2.0

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using an  extension called `yii2-adldap-module` in  `Yii2`. So in web.php inside components I have set values like this

```
'ldap' => [
        'class'=>'Edvlerblog\Ldap',
        'options'=> ['ad_port'      => 389,
        'domain_controllers'    => array( '*.*.*.*'),
        'account_suffix' =>  '@*.*.*',
        'base_dn' => "DC=*,DC=**,DC=**",
        'admin_username' => '***',
        'admin_password' => '*****',
]
```

Now I want to change the value of `'base_dn'` dynamically.
For example before using the following codes inside a controller method

```
$usernames =  \Yii::$app->ldap->user()->all();
        print_r($usernames);
```

I want to change `'base_dn'`  . How this can be done in `Yii2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[yii2-adldap-module](https://github.com/edvler/yii2-adldap-module) is [just a wrapper of adLDAP](https://github.com/edvler/yii2-adldap-module#documentation).
Then, you can do it by calling "setBaseDn()" method like :

```
$newBaseDn = 'DC=NewDN,...';
Yii::$app->ldap->setBaseDn($newBaseDn);
```

see:

https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP/blob/master/lib/adLDAP/adLDAP.php#L215

Comment: How to change add Sizelimit to  \Yii::$app->ldap->user()->all(); It is showing ldap_search(): Partial search results returned: Sizelimit exceeded ?

Comment: @user7282 It's based on a LDAP server's config. see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php#refsect1-function.ldap-search-parameters